# Searchable List of icons

Tags: list, listview, flutter, dart, icons

I would like to create a dropdown or a list of all free FontAwesomeIcons to allow the user choose the one he/she like more. Also if You write something, the list have to filter the icons(that´s optional).

```
  List<IconData> fontAwesomeIcons = [FontAwesomeIcons.accessibleIcon,FontAwesomeIcons.americanSignLanguageInterpreting,FontAwesomeIcons.assistiveListeningSystems,FontAwesomeIcons.audioDescription,];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
DropdownButton<IconData>(
 value: dropdownValue,
         onChanged: (IconDatanewValue) {
          setState(() {
            dropdownValue = newValue;
          });
        },
        items: <IconData>[FontAwesomeIcons.accessibleIcon,FontAwesomeIcons.americanSignLanguageInterpreting,FontAwesomeIcons.assistiveListeningSystems,FontAwesomeIcons.audioDescription]
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<IconData>>((IconData value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<IconData>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          })
          .toList(),
      ),
```

The `DropdownMenuItem` is a class used to represent the items.

`onChanged` is called when the user selects an item.
Check the docs for more information:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html

Comment: Thank you!!! By the way, is there anyway to get all the FontAwesomeIcons into an array or I have to write them by hand one by one?

Comment: dont think so, but you can find all the icons here https://github.com/brianegan/font_awesome_flutter/blob/master/example/lib/icons.dart

Comment: That was what I was lookign for. Thank you again!